# Conflicts with D2D1 and graphics card

Tags: c++

My VGA-Card is **Radeon HD5600.**

```
hr = m_pRenderTarget->CreateBitmapFromWicBitmap( pConverter, NULL, &m_pBitmap );
```

This function returns so slowly.

I tried after uninstalling the graphic driver.

Then, that function returns so fast.

How can I solve the problem?